# Not understanding the use of FileWriter class

Tags: java

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
public class ProductInfoDwnld{
static String abc;
public static void addProductToCart(String a_CartId, String a_productId, String a_desc, String a_price){
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try{
        File yourFile = new File(a_CartId);
        // Check if yourFile exists
        if(!yourFile.exists())
            yourFile.createNewFile(); // Create a new yourFile if it does not exist
        else{
            try {
                FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(yourFile,true);
                fileWrite.write(a_productId + " " + a_desc + " " + a_price); // write(String str);
                fileWrite.close();
            }catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream(yourFile,false);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    String CartID = "001.txt";
    String productId="001", Desc = "Laptop", price="20000Rs";
    addProductToCart(CartID,productId,Desc,price);
}
}
```

Using the code below I am trying to write into the file 001.txt using FileWriter class. But the data is not being written into the file. I am not able to understand the reason. Need help

Comment: Try removing this line: `FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream(yourFile,false);`

Comment: ya its working after removing that line. thanks.

Comment: @Lizzie I know it got working for you. But do you know why it happened like that?

Comment: @smit Because the boolean append in the FileOutputStream constructor was false so data couldn't be appended into the file

Comment: @Lizzie Thats true. [See FileOutputStream API for more info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File, boolean) ) . I will also suggest to close the resources once your are done in `finally` [See The finally Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reformatted your code a touch:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ProductInfoDwnld{
    static String abc;
    public static void addProductToCart(String a_CartId, String a_productId, String a_desc, String a_price){
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try{
            File yourFile = new File(a_CartId);
            // Check if yourFile exists
            if(!yourFile.exists()) {
                yourFile.createNewFile(); // Create a new yourFile if it does not exist
            }

                    // Note you had an else block here:
                    // If the file didn't exist you only would create it
                    //  and not write any data to it.
                    // If the file exists you'd write data to it.
                    // I removed the else block

            try {
                FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(yourFile,true);
                fileWrite.write(a_productId + " " + a_desc + " " + a_price); // write(String str);
                fileWrite.flush();
                fileWrite.close();
            }catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String CartID = "001.txt";
        String productId="001", Desc = "Laptop", price="20000Rs";
        addProductToCart(CartID,productId,Desc,price);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The line `FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream(yourFile,false);` is overwriting your file. Remove it and it will work

Comment: +1 its true. YOu should also attach API link to your question. [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File, boolean))

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
fileWrite.flush();
```

before you close FileWriter object.

Comment: Should not need that unless something else is wrong in his/her code.

Answer (score 0):

I faced that problem once with an existing file. Check that you have write permissions on the existing file. Also upon file creation check that the file permissions are set correctly.

Comment: If he/she has not permission to write the file, it would raise an `IOException`.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the file writing happening inside the else loop. If the file doesn't exist, then the first iteration would just create the file and exit. It wouldn't do the actual writing. Try this:

```
if(!yourFile.exists())
        yourFile.createNewFile(); // Create a new yourFile if it does not exist

    try {
        FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(yourFile,true);
        fileWrite.write(a_productId + " " + a_desc + " " + a_price); // write(String str);
        fileWrite.close();
    }catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```